# Connecting Hootsuite data to BigQuery without having to manually exporting dataset from Hootsuite

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

Is there a way to export Hootsuite data into BigQuery or Google Data Studio without having to manually exporting the data from Hootsuite and loading the data into BigQuery or Google Data Studio?

Is there a way to connect the data to BigQuery or Google Data Studio similar to Google analytics?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there's no Hootsuite connector for Data Studio listed in their [data sources](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-sources). It is also not supported in BigQuery's native [Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-service-overview#supported_data_sources) data sources, nor through third-party solutions in [Google Cloud Platform Marketplace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/).

There's a [connector](https://tray.io/connectors/google-bigquery-hootsuite-integrations) developed by the third-party tray.io; however, it seems to be a paid service.

You could also try automating the process with the [Hootsuite API](https://developer.hootsuite.com/docs). First exporting the data and then [loading it into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data).

In the meantime, I went ahead and created a [Feature Request to the BigQuery team](https://issuetracker.google.com/146669234) so they can consider adding Hootsuite as a data source. You can click the star icon next to the title to subscribe and you'll receive e-mails regarding its progress.